# How to scroll text from left to right in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to show entered text in canvas in scrollable form in left to right direction using javascript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488996/create-a-scrollable-text-inside-canvas

Answer (score 0):

you can use css for that just add this ccs-rule to your canvas:

```
#Canvas{
overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Example:
https://codepen.io/Joachim8790/pen/odQXzg

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply i will try this one.